# intersection of maximal ideals in a polynomial ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Given $A=K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ a polynomial ring on a field $K$, let $p(x)\in A$ be an element, and $M_1,\dots,M_s$ some maximal ideals.

Is it true that
$$\cap(M_i,p) = (\cap M_i,p)?$$

I obtained that it's true if $K$ is algebraically closed, since you can work well with their varieties, but I don't know how to dis/prove it in general.

---

Some addictional facts:

I proved that, in any case,

$$\cap(M_i,p) = \sqrt{(\cap M_i,p)}$$
So it's sufficient to prove that the ideal is radical.

Another thing I discovered is that this fact is equivalent to

> For every radical $0$-dimensional ideal $Q$, if $Q\subseteq J$, then $J$ is radical

Comment: Can you show that the only case of relevance is when $p\in \M_i$?

Comment: maybe when $p\not\in M_i$ for every $i$

Comment: I don't understand. If $p\not\in M_i$ for all $i$, both sides are just the whole ring.

Comment: ok, but how do you prove it if $p\in M_1$, but $p\not\in M_2$?

Comment: Did you try? $p\not\in M_2$ implies $(M_2,p)=A$. Similarly, $(M_1\cap M_2,p)=(M_1,p)$.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it.. Maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just found the solution.

It's obvious that 
$$\cap(M_i,p) \supseteq (\cap M_i,p)$$

but if $p\not\in M_1,\dots,M_r$, $p\in M_{r+1},\dots,M_s$ then
$$\exists m_i\in M_i, \exists a_i : m_i+a_ip =1 \quad \forall i\le r$$
so
$$q\in \cap(M_i,p) \iff q\in M_{r+1}\cap\dots\cap M_s$$
$$q=q\prod(m_i+a_ip)=q\prod m_i + p(\dots)\in (\cap M_i,p)$$
resulting in
$$\cap(M_i,p) \subseteq (\cap M_i,p)$$